Why does ReadAsStreamAsync continue download after connection drops and reconnects?
I'm downloading a large file using the following code:
using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
    await using var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
await using var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, 81920, cancellationToken);

I fail to understand why this continues to download the file even if the connection drops and reconnects. I tried to set the following to stop it retrying
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

but it still continues to download after connection drops and reconnects.
For one file I disconnected for more than 5 minutes before reconnecting and it still continued to download.
What's it in the HttpClient that makes this possible?

Are you using a sniffer to determine that the file continues to download?  HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer.  TCP is reliable that every packets is ACK and when an ACK is not sent the datagram is sent again up to 3 times.   The closing of a connection is also ACK.  You have to check the sequence numbers to see if packets are sent more than once.  The sequence number will be duplicated when a packet is not ACK.
